# How to set up zoho mail in odoo outgoing mail server odoo14

Tags: email, odoo, zoho

I'm trying to configure access to a catch-all mail hosted by Zoho.com with my own domain. Everything worked fine before, with a Gmail address (not my domain, just a regular Gmail account) but with Zoho I can't send emails.

1. Incoming is configured for IMAP and working flawlessly.
2. Outgoing is configured as follows:

Description: Zoho (catch-all)

Priority: 10

SMTP Server: smtp.zoho.com

SMTP Port: 465

Debugging: [not flagged]

Connection Security: SSL/TLS

Username: <my_catch_all_email@mydomain.com)< p="">

Password:

The [Test Connection] works but when sending emails from any application I get the infamous message "Error:
Mail Delivery Failed
Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'None'.
SMTPDataError: 553
Relaying disallowed as xxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx". Couldn't find much help on the net so I'm posting here...

Thanks in advance for any help!